# convert a filename to google standards using emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a bunch of files which I have to convert the names of to google standards. 
I could go and change it manually but I was wondering if there is an emacs binding for the same.

Basically I need to convert

- FileName.cpp to file_name.cpp
- FileName.h to file_name.h

and inside the cpp files

`#include <FileName.h>` to `#include <file_name.h>`

Comment: Someone will give you the Dired answer soon, I hope.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways -

1. Applicable if you are using Mac OS - Partial Solution : This will only change the name of the file but will not change the file name inside the cpp file. Macbook has a tool called automator where you specify folder where all your file exists and then take action say edit the file name to a certain pattern. I use this regularly to change the name of the image files that I download from web or music files from Itunes.
2. you can write a shell script to do what you need.
3. Write a C++ method to do that.